# Post hoc test 2x2 design

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

I have a relatively simple 2x2 design. I give a hypothetical example.  I have a continuous variable Y (Plant Growth) and I have 2 factors with 2 levels; Temperature (warm/cold) and Condition (Fertilizer, no Fertilizer).

I did an Anova (Plant Growth~Temperature*Condition) and get the following p-values:

- Temperature: p = 0.01
- Condition: p = 0.002
- Temperature*Condition: p = 0.245

As the interaction is not significant, I do not want to do every single comparison in a post hoc test. Instead, I want to see if Condition has a significant effect on plant growth under warm temperatures, and I also want to know if Condition has a significant effect on plant growth under cold conditions.

Now I wondered what the correct way of doing this is? Would I do a simple t-test under Condition cold and another one under Condition warm? If that is possible, would I have to correct for multiple comparisons (I guess so)? It doesn't seem to make sense to do a post hoc test in that case.

Comment: Do the values 0.01, 0.002 and 0.245 refer to p values?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I should have mentioned that!

Answer (score 2):

**You do not need to do a post-hoc test.**

Because the interaction term is not significant, we know that the main effect of Condition is significant at *both* Temperatures.

Comment: Many thanks for that fast reply and the clarification. That does make a lot of sense. I must have misunderstood this.

Comment: If the answer was useful, please help others by accepting it. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't answer that but I actually do not know how to accept an answer.

Comment: I have, however, a follow up question in terms of how to display the statistical results in a boxplot or barplot. A common thing after a post hoc test would be to add letters over the, in this case, 4 bars. But as I didn't do all the individual comparisons I guess I cannot do that. What is a common way to do that?

Comment: It should be obvious to the reader once you draw the barplot with confidence intervals. The figure legend can state the results of the significance tests.